# How can we get secondVC json value in firstVC without going to secondVC in swift

Tags: json, swift, pushviewcontroller, keychainitemwrapper

my firstVC json contains all other view controller json ids... here i want before pushing to other view controller i need to compare it with home home json id here which 2 ids are same i need to push thatVC.. so here without going to any other view controller how can we get their ids to compare in homeVC... please help me here.

**I have tried two ways:**

**1) declaring variable in secondVC and assign secondVC id value to it and calling it in firstVC**

in firstVC code:

```
let goVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController

var goId: String = goVC.secndId ?? ""
print("the goid is \(goId)")// getting nil
if(goId == allIdArray)
{
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(goVC, animated: true)
}
```

in secondVC:

```
var secndId: String?
secndId = jsonObj["sid"] as? String
```

**2) storing secondVC json id with keychain wrapper and retriving it in firstVC**

in first:

```
let goVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController

let goId: String = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "sid") ?? ""
print("the goid is \(goId)")// getting nil
if(goId == allIdArray)
{
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(goVC, animated: true)
}
```

in secondVC:

```
var secndId: String?
self.secndId = jsonObj["sid"] as? String
KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.secndId ?? "", forKey: "sid")
```

here allIdArray contain allVC ids, and sid is secondVC json id

in both ways i am getting nil why ?? i want compare secondvc id in firstvc without goning to secondvc.

please help me in above code.

Comment: Your secondVC isn't initialized, thus all data inside it and all methods didn't run yet, thus not assigning any IDs to your variables.
I am not sure I understood what you're trying to accomplish, but you can create a dictionary with view controllers types. I will write a response now.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole logic design isn't great, but if I was to answer straight to your question, and taking into consideration that the explanations aren't great either, here is a suggestion for you:

```
  let vcID = 1

  let viewControllers = [1 : FirstVC.self, 2 : SecondVC.self, 3 : ThirdVC.self]
  for (id, vcType) in viewControllers {
     if id == vcID {
         //assuming that you assign storyboard identifiers exactly matching classes' names, otherwise this guard statement won't succeed
         guard let goToVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(vcType)") else { return }
         //if you need to pass any data before you present this VC, then you will need to safely cast into known VC types
         self.present(goToVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
  }
```